# save strings from MS SQL 2008 in JSON format over ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ios, json

i build a web service with Visual Studio 2010. the Language is C# and ASP.NET 3.5.

the Webserver sends the data from my ms sql server 2008 to an iPhone with JSON format.

but i receive one string value with all the data from SQL Server. 
i want that the web service sends me the data separate so that i can consume it better on the iPhone.

here is my c# class:

```
   namespace WebService1
{
    public class RaumklassenHelper
    {



        internal static string Raumklasse()
        {
            string raumKlassenObject = "";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT BEZEICHNUNG FROM RAUMKLASSE", con))
            {

                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {


                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"]  != DBNull.Value)
                         {

                              raumKlassenObject += rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString();
                         }

                    }


                }
            }

            return raumKlassenObject;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my web method:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public string Raumklasse()
        {
            return RaumklassenHelper.Raumklasse();
        }
```

how can send the strings spereate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return an array:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public string[] Raumklasse()
{
    return RaumklassenHelper.Raumklasse();
}
```

and then obviously adapt the data retrieval method:

```
public class RaumklassenHelper
{
    internal static string[] Raumklasse()
    {
        List<string> raumKlassenObject = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT BEZEICHNUNG FROM RAUMKLASSE", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        raumKlassenObject.Add(rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return raumKlassenObject.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i must return the strings in json format. because my iPhone still shows me all the string in one row

Comment: What format does your client application expects the JSON to be?

Comment: And how does this format look like? Could you provide an example of the expected format?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using reading the results into a DataTable and then using linq to query the result set makes it very easy to return json formatted reponses.

```
namespace WebService1
{
 public class RaumklassenHelper
 {
    internal static string Raumklasse()
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT BEZEICHNUNG FROM RAUMKLASSE", con))
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            tbl.Load(rdr);
            rdr.Close();
            var linqResults = from DataRow row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
                              select new { raumKlassenObject = row.Field<string>("BEZEICHNUNG") };
            js.Serialize(linqResults, sb);
            string returnJSON = sb.ToString();
            return returnJSON;
        }
    }
}
}
```